# biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)

Tags: biblatex

Is there a '`biblatex` in a nutshell' guide out there?
I'd like if someone explained to me the essentials on how to use `biblatex` (what lines I have to write in my document, which files I have to have, how many times and what I have to compile), so then I can go to http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf to customise it further.

Comment: [This question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/215) Might be of interest.

Answer (score 294, accepted):

A minimal document for `biblatex` would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
% \bibliography{<database>} % deprecated
\addbibresource{<database>.<extension>}
\begin{document}
\cite{<some-ref>}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

which requires a `<database>` file in `.bib` format. You then run:

1. LaTeX
2. Biber
3. LaTeX

Normally, you'd also select a bibliography style by loading this an an optional argument to the `biblatex` line

```
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
```

See [How to use biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26516/how-to-use-biber/34136)  and [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations) for more if your editor is not set up to offer Biber 'out of the box'.

---

For some time, `biblatex` has supported two 'backends' (the program that extracts  references from the `.bib` file), BibTeX and Biber. As of version 2, Biber is the default backend, so I have used it above. Biber is more powerful and works natively with UTF-8 input, but where it is not available one can fall back on more limited support using BibTeX. The workflow is pretty similar:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}
% \bibliography{<database>} % deprecated
\addbibresource{<database>.<extension>}
\begin{document}
\cite{<some-ref>}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and you then need to run

1. LaTeX
2. BibTeX
3. LaTeX

As you'll see, this is very little difference from using Biber: basically replace 'Biber' with 'BibTeX'.

You should use the '8-bit' version of BibTeX as a minimum, rather than the ancient 7-bit BibTeX. At the Command line, this is used by doing

```
bibtex8 --wolfgang <filename>
```

where `<filename>` is the name of your LaTeX file.

There is more you can do, but this should get you started.

---

Recent versions of `biblatex` have deprecated

```
\bibliography{<database>} % Must be .bib
```

in favour of the more general

```
 \addbibresource{<database>.<extension>}
```

The latter is more general, but you must include the file extension (usually `.bib`).

Comment: I beleive that newbie should try BibTeX rather then biblatex. The biblatex package is backward incompartible with standard BibTeX (please don't mix bibtex.exe with BibTeX), and biblatex is not supported by _all_ journals.

Comment: @Igor: The question is about `biblatex`, so my answer should I hope be reasonable. I'm not sure what you mean by 'please don't mix bibtex.exe with BibTeX': with either a _traditional_ BibTeX style or with `biblatex` you still need to run BibTeX (unless you are using Biber with `biblatex`). To do that, most people will be using an IDE which will say 'BibTeX': it's the chose of loading `biblatex` or using `\bibliographystyle` that determines what BibTeX _does_.

Comment: I should add that I doubt you'll find _any_ journals supporting `biblatex` (it needs e-TeX, which seems to be rare on publication systems, and many journals actually convert to XML at some stage rather than typeset from TeX source directly).

Comment: so far I've always used bibtex, but every time I forget how it works (I assume the same will happen with biblatex). I thought of switching to bibtex as I'm trying to find a quick solution to the usual problem of tweaking the citation system (e.g. having bibentry for 'title Elements de Geometrie Algebrique, author Grothendieck etc...' but no matter what the citation style is I always want it to print as [EGA]). A quick solution to that problem working with bibtex would make my day as well!

Comment: @slackenerny: Sounds like you want to use biblatex's "shorthand" feature. Ask a question, and I'll try to come up with a working example. :-)

Comment: According to section 3.5.1 of the `biblatex` documentation, you should use `\addbibresource` instead of `\bibliography`, which is deprecated.

Comment: @doncherry Yes, that's true. (I'm a bit uncomfortable with deprecating a core LaTeX2e macro, but I'll note it)

Comment: @Igor: I strongly disagree. Of course, if you're forced to use `bibtex`(because of journal guidelines or for whatever reason) then do it. But then the whole question becomes moot anyway. But if you don't have to use traditional `bibtex`, for heaven's sake do yourself the favor and use `biblatex`. It's so much better, that you shouldn't even waste time thinking about changing or not.

Comment: @JosephWright I think the 8-bit BibTeX implementation also needs `backend=bibtex8`.

Comment: Does not work for me with backend=biber. References are not recognised and file is not found. IDK most of latex users for me seems to be students it should not be so complicated. I stick with backend=bibtext. When people tell me use `x' because it is better - then make it work out of the box. OO languages are way easier to understand than this declarative nightmare... really?

Comment: @Aubergine Did you run `biber` rather than `bibtex` with the `backend=biber` option?

Comment: can I use XeLaTeX -> Biber -> XeLaTeX?

Comment: 273 upvotes for an answer, that does not even include a bib file...

Comment: @MartinErhardt It's a _generic_ answer: I mention database files, but they are not `biblatex`-specific so belong elsewhere

Answer (score 70):

`biblatex` comes with a variety of built-in bibliography/citation style families (numeric, alphabetic, authoryear, authortitle, verbose), and there's a growing number of custom styles. That said, here's how to approximately emulate the output of the traditional BibTeX styles `plain`, `abbrv`, `unsrt`, and `alpha`:

`plain` --> `\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}`

`abbrv` --> `\usepackage[style=numeric,giveninits=true]{biblatex}`

`unsrt` --> `\usepackage[style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}`

`alpha` --> `\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}`

In the first three instances, you may omit `style=numeric` as this is the default style of `biblatex`.

Answer (score 40):

Section 1 of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), which you're referring to, reads:

> This document is a systematic reference manual for the `biblatex` package. Look
>   at the sample documents which ship with `biblatex` [[1](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex//doc/examples)] to get a first impression. For
>   a quick start guide, browse §§ 1.1, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 3.1, 3.3, 3.6, 3.7, 3.11.

I just got started with `biblatex` by reading these sections (and trying out the things described) and I feel like they gave me a thorough overview of the basic functions. Of course, there's a lot among this information that you can just skim or skip, but I think it's good to know what options are out there.

I read into the German article [that Herbert referred to](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13512/4012) as well, but I didn't feel like it really told me what to do and how to get started, but perhaps that's because this is the first time I ever used some kind of bibliography tool in LaTeX.

If you need to decide whether to use BibTeX or Biber as a backend, Alan Munn's extensive (but comprehensible!) answer to [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/4012) might be of help to you. I decided to use Biber.

Concludingly, I recommend going straight to the source and getting some first-hand information by reading the mentioned parts of the `biblatex` documentation.

Comment: You might want to add that the (great) sample documents can be found on your computer in the Tex tree at `texmf/doc/latex/biblatex/examples` or [online](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples).

Comment: You can browse the biblatex examples in the new TeX tree in your texlive distro: `file:////usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/doc/latex/biblatex/examples/`

Comment: My miktex distro was at `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\doc\latex\biblatex\examples`.

Answer (score 34):

I too would like to find what the OP is asking about (an introductory-type document on BibLaTeX). I haven't found one yet, but here are two documents that I did find useful towards that end:

http://tex.aanhet.net/rugtex/course/4bibtex.pdf

Broken link now, but what I found most helpful is here:

## 3.5 The latest and greatest: biblatex

A radical reimplementation of bibliography support is biblatex. Bibliography styles aren’t writ- ten in the unfamiliar .bst syntax but in LaTEX, and the role of BibTEX is reduced to collecting and sorting the bibliographic data. LaTEX itself selects, arranges and formats the information from the bibliographic entries. Advantages include

- many variations in bibliography style can be realized simply with
  package options, without editing .bst files
- better support for non-Western languages
- more citation options, because LaTEX has access to all the
  bibliographic information
- easy per-chapter bibliographies

Fortunately, an old BibTEX database is still compatible with biblatex.

*Getting started with biblatex.* You can easily experiment with biblatex. For starters, use the package option natbib or natbib=true so that you don’t need to change the cite commands in your LaTEX source just yet. Latexbib uses mostly the same database format and requires only a few small changes in the preamble and at the end of your document. Biblatex preamble commands for the example below:

```
\usepackage[style=numeric,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{bibdemo}
```

and near the end:

```
\printbibliography
```

Note that with biblatex the \bibliography command should be in the preamble.

http://www.charlietanksley.net/pdf/latex-footnote-citations.pdf

This is now (8/10/2013) also a broken link, and that's too bad because I found the document very helpful two years ago. I still have both these files, but I can't do justice to this second one in the answer here. I've attached an image of the first page, but would gladly post the pdf if it was possible.
[image: A BibLaTeX demonstration (plus the code), by Charlie Tanksley, May 19, 2010]

Comment: This feels more like a comment than an answer, and the first of the two links is not about `biblatex`.

Comment: @JosephWright: True, but the second link is useful.

Comment: The first of the two links has about 1.5-2 pages on biblatex starting on pg. 6, section 3.5 (with a nice introductory feel to it, from my newbie perspective), but thanks @JosephWright for the feedback re comment vs. answer. Still learning TeX.sx, and all that feedback is helpful to me, so thanks (can't upvote comments, I guess, so maybe thanks are ok in comments? feedback welcome on this too).

Comment: @TeXnewbie: You should be able to upvotes comments by now, so that question's solved. As for the rest, I suggest you incorporate that information directly into your answer. Editing a post often is a good response to a comment, keeping in mind the Wiki aspect of tex.sx. Furthermore, it often is nicer to use the title of a document you're linking to as link text instead of the blank URL, as can be seen in the other answers here.

Comment: Neither of these links appear to exist

Comment: That's regrettable. Thanks for the heads' up though. I've updated the answer with some details as I still have both files.

Comment: You shouldn't really use `\bibliography` at all, but `\addbibresource`. Note that the latter requires the full filename,  e.g `mybib.bib`, not just `mybib`.

Comment: @TeXnewbie, the first link is available via wayback machine [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20120907000209/http://tex.aanhet.net/rugtex/course/4bibtex.pdf)

Comment: @TeXnewbie Documents similar to the first seem to exist at http://facultyfp.salisbury.edu/despickler/personal/Resources/LatexHandouts/3bibtex.pdf and http://tex.aanhet.net/rugtex/course/latexcourse.pdf, perhaps you want to put one of these links in your answer? Also, it’d be great if you could use the blockquote markup to indicate the quoted passages.

Comment: Thanks @doncherry for the pointer. I'm a newbie with MML too, so I'm not quite sure how to use the blockquote markup. Could you show me?

Comment: Here is Charlie Tankslie's tutorial: https://github.com/charlietanksley/charlietanksley_net/blob/master/build/pdfs/latex-footnote-citations.pdf

Comment: The first passage cited can also be found in http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/info/latexcourse-rug/latexcourse-rug.pdf as section C.5.

Comment: The first document cited, by the Imperial University Groningen, is archived: https://web.archive.org/web/20120907000209/http://tex.aanhet.net/rugtex/course/4bibtex.pdf

Answer (score 24):

If you are familiar with German, you'll find a two-part introduction in "Die TeXnische Komödie", the journal of DANTE:
[DTK 2/2008](http://www.dante.de/DTK/Ausgaben/2008-2.pdf), [DTK 4/2008](http://www.dante.de/DTK/Ausgaben/dtk08-4.pdf).

You can start with one of the default settings, e.g.:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\bibliography{...} % better use \addbibresource, according to the comments
...
\nocite{*} % adds all entries in the bib file to the bibliography
\printbibliography
```

There are a lot of examples in your local TeX installation (at `texmf/doc/latex/biblatex/examples/`).

Comment: As I remarked at Joseph's answer: According to section 3.5.1 of the biblatex documentation, you should use \addbibresource instead of \bibliography, which is deprecated. (Also see Joseph's comments).

Comment: deprecated is _not_ not defined ...

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I follow. I just wanted to say that the author of `biblatex` recommends using `\addbibresource`, so I thought it might be a good idea to endorse this usage in a beginner's guide.

Comment: @doncherry Use of `\bibliography` (at least for now) is acceptable. `\addbibresource` is probably recommended [because it offers many more features](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21439/4483).

Comment: @user2478 It [*is defined*](https://www.google.com/search?q=deprecated) but not the word *depreciated*

Comment: Bingo: It is an word for *depreciated*: Oxford dictionary: *2.
another term for depreciate (sense 2).
"he deprecates the value of children's television"*

Answer (score 13):

To add to the other resources here, simply for the sake of having them in one convenient place, I have put together a **medium-length** introduction, intended to be an "easier read" than the full manual, which can be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/PaulStanley/biblatex-tutorial/releases). It's aimed at the "ordinary user" not someone writing a complete style.

Although the current release remains a draft, and I expect to update it, it is complete, and basically "there" subject to some nit-picking. Chapter 1 and the Quick Start Guide (p 109) are introductory.

[image]

Comment: By itself, this is a nice read, but it also makes navigating the package's manual easier.

Comment: I added a screenshot from the PDF (I would make the `commas` red so that no one will ever forget them :)). It's really nice. I hope there will be another release in the future.

Answer (score 7):

For French-speaking people, this [site](http://bertrandmasson.free.fr/index.php?article27/biblatex-explique-a-mademoiselle-michu-etudiante-en-sciences-humaines) tries to popularise LaTeX among students in humanities. You can download from this page a .pdf of about 60 pages entitled "Biblatex expliqué à Mademoiselle Michu, étudiante en sciences humaines" (something like "Biblatex explained to Miss Jane Bloggs, a Student in Humanities"), that I find a rather good and simple approach.

Comment: Be aware though that this document is quite old (from September 2010) and might therefore contain outdated information and use deprecated commands. (It does not mention Biber, for example; the new backend is superior to BibTeX in many ways.) It also contains some spelling errors in English command/field names.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a minimal working example.

First file, `doc.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\bibliography{database.bib}
\begin{document}
According to \cite{foo1999} blah blah.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Second file, `database.bib`:

```
@article{foo1999,
  title={Title},
  author={Doe, John},
  journal={International Journal of Nonsense},
  year={1999}
}
```

To compile:

```
pdflatex doc
bibtex doc
pdflatex doc
pdflatex doc
```

Result in `doc.pdf`:

[image: Screenshot of <code>doc.pdf</code>]

Comment: Isn't all of that already contained in Josephs answer along the information that `\biibliography` is deprecated?

Comment: @Johannes_B: This is obviously based on Joseph's answer, but in a MWE form, i.e. you can just copy-paste it and have it work, unlike the original which requires more attention. I'll make it CW.

Comment: It will fail with `biber` as backend.

Comment: @Johannes_B Not being a user of `biber`, I don't know how it differs from `bibtex`. I don't see another answer giving a clear example for `biber, so please do edit my answer to provide a MWE that works for it too!

Comment: The `backend=bibtex` in `\usepackage[...]{biblatex}` seems to be crucial (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/72860/81156).

Comment: `biblatex`'s default backend is Biber (`backend=biber,`). BibTeX is still supported as a legacy option, but crucially not all advanced features will work with BibTeX as they required Biber. The `biblatex` documentation now assumes you use Biber. For most people switching to Biber is as easy as saying `backend=biber,` and running Biber instead of BibTeX, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864.

Answer (score 5):

Overleaf have a series of very accessible posts on the matter of bibliographies with LaTeX.

The main article dealing with basic `biblatex` is https://overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_in_LaTeX. The nice thing for Overleaf users is that the article links example documents that can be used to experiment with the presented settings.

The two lists https://overleaf.com/learn/latex/Biblatex_bibliography_styles and https://overleaf.com/learn/latex/Biblatex_citation_styles give a short run-down of common bibliography and citation styles.

There is also another tutorial-like article: https://overleaf.com/learn/latex/Articles/Getting_started_with_BibLaTeX with a video (originally from ShareLaTeX).

Finally, there is https://overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Using_bibliographies_on_Overleaf, which deals mainly with `.bib` files.

**When reading these articles, keep in mind that often online editors run Biber automatically for you (Overleaf does that via `latexmk`) and that their tutorials therefore do not usually touch on this otherwise crucial step.** See [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864)

Answer (score 4):

If you read French, you could look at http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latex-sciences-humaines.

Answer (score 4):

If you can read a little of French, [here are the slides](http://gte.univ-littoral.fr/members/dbitouze/pub/latex/diapositives-cours-d/conference-n-6/downloadFile/file/en-ligne6.pdf) of a LaTeX course I give about `biblatex` and `csquotes`.

Answer (score 2):

- I make tutorials about BiBLaTeX in my spare time -- have a look -- maybe it helps.
- For the experts here, I didn't choose UTF-8, please don't make a war about it :).

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-Wl6F3zpJVwcDHK2rg9bDEEMjo70zp87

[image]

Comment: name closes to manual, LOL

Answer (score 0):

A quit nice cheatsheet is available here:
https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-cheatsheet

Answer (score 0):

I found this website to be a really nice practical explanation of how to "trace macros" in biblatex, which I previously found very confusing: http://www.khirevich.com/latex/biblatex/

Ooops, a few minutes later... I notice that @Siarhei Khirevich has already posted his website to the `tex.stackexchange.com` here: [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex/114746#114746)

I have opted to keep my answer to this question, because I believe that the website provided by @Siarhei Khirevich deserves to be more widely known (I found it through `Google` rather than on `tex.stackexchange.com`).